# Return successively-yielded values as an array when generator is done

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I would like to know if it is possible to return successively-yielded values as an array when the generator is done. This is what I have tried so far, where I add a return statement at the end of the generator and attempt to destructure the output:

```
function ajax(url) {
  fetch(url).then(data => data.json()).then(data => dataGen.next(data))
}

function* steps() {
  const beers = yield ajax('http://api.react.beer/v2/search?q=hops&type=beer');

  const wes = yield ajax('https://api.github.com/users/wesbos');

  const fatJoe = yield ajax('https://api.discogs.com/artists/51988');

  return [beers, wes, fatJoe]
}

const dataGen = steps();
const [beers, wes, fatJoe] = dataGen.next(); // kick it off
```

However, none of the values are returned:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: beers is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: wes is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: fatJoe is not defined
```

Comment: You have to call next until you get to the return statement before you get the returned array

Comment: I see. Should I also use `yield` instead of `return` for the last statement?

Comment: The requested URL's have issues. What is expected result? The resulting `Promise` value of `fetch()` call? Why do you not use `Promise.all()`?

Comment: @guest271314 if I console log beers, wes, and fatJoe, remove `return [beers, wes, fatJoe]`, and replace `const [beers, wes, fatJoe] = dataGen.next();` with `dataGen.next();`, I get 3 Objects. Also, this is based on an online course, and I am just modifying the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interpret Question correctly you can use `yield*`, pass `steps()` call to `Promise.all()`, `.then()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Generators</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

  function ajax(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(data => data.json()).then(data => data)
  }

  function* steps() {
    yield* [
             ajax('data:application/json,[1]')
             , ajax('data:application/json,[2]')
             , ajax('data:application/json,[3]')
           ];
  }

  // kick it off
  Promise.all(steps())
  .then(([beers, wes, fatJoe]) => 
    console.log(beers, wes, fatJoe)
  )
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or `Promise.all()` without generator function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Generators</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

  function ajax(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(data => data.json()).then(data => data)
  }

  function steps() {
    return [
             ajax('data:application/json,[1]')
             , ajax('data:application/json,[2]')
             , ajax('data:application/json,[3]')
           ];
  }

  // kick it off
  Promise.all(steps())
  .then(([beers, wes, fatJoe]) => 
    console.log(beers, wes, fatJoe)
  )
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to call beers, wes, and fatJoe on the console, but it tells me that they are undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by _"call beers, wes, and fatJoe on the console"_? Are you trying to access asynchronous `Promise` values outside of `Promise` chain?

Comment: `.then(data => data)` is no-op.

Comment: So by that I mean when I run the code on my browser, I would like to be able to type `beers` and see the console return the value associated with it. The end goal is I want to be able to use those variables after the `Promise.all` block

Comment: @valencra These variables are available only inside the callback function. They're not global variables.

Comment: You need to use `.then()` or `.catch()` to access values returned by `Promise`

Comment: Is there a way to access them outside the callback function?

Comment: @valencra Generally, no. `fetch()` and `Response.json()` returns a `Promise`

Comment: @valencra See this question: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3853934)

Comment: @valencra `steps` function could be composed utilizing rest element `const ajax = url => fetch(url).then(data => data.json()).then(data => data)
const steps = (...requests) => requests;

  // kick it off
  Promise.all(steps(ajax('data:application/json,[1]')
             , ajax('data:application/json,[2]')
             , ajax('data:application/json,[3]')))
  .then(([beers, wes, fatJoe]) => 
    console.log(beers, wes, fatJoe)
  )`

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Stop using generators as a replacement for `async`/`await`. If you want to do that, you need to use a proper asynchronous runner such as the `co` library or `Bluebird.coroutine`. But their era is the past now, `async`/`await` is readily available in recent browsers (and in transpilers anyway)!

```
function ajax(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(data => data.json());
//^^^^^^
}

async function steps() {
  const beers = await ajax('http://api.react.beer/v2/search?q=hops&type=beer');
  const wes = await ajax('https://api.github.com/users/wesbos');
  const fatJoe = await ajax('https://api.discogs.com/artists/51988');

  return [beers, wes, fatJoe];
}

const dataPromise = steps(); // kick it off
dataPromise.then(([beers, wes, fatJoe]) => {
  console.log(…); // use results here
});
```

(or alternatively await `dataPromise` in another async function)